# Xcode fails app install after iOS8.4 and Xcode 6.4 updates

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

Out of nothing my app won't install on my test device (iPhone 6 on 8.4) anymore. I get a message saying "App installation failed. An unknown error has occurred". I updated today to iOS 8.4 and Xcode 6.4 could this have something to do with it?

App still runs on the simulator. Also if I change the name of the top folder I don't get the error and it works fine. Is there some path that I need to change and I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried to completely remove the app from the device, clean the project and run again?

Comment: I did, tried "Clean", "Clean Build Folder", removing the app and restarting both devices.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is now happening to me daily. The fix I've found is to clean the build folder. To clean the build folder, go to the product menu and hold down the option key. The "Clean" option will change to "Clean Build Folder."

If that doesn't work, then clean the derived data folder. Window -> Projects -> Select your Project -> Delete derived data folder.

As a last resort, you can delete and reinstall the app.

Comment: I did, tried all three. Still the same error. I also tried soft resetting both my iPhone and MacBook.

Comment: Hmm. Did you also try deleting the derived data folder? Window - Projects - Select Project - Delete derived data.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect that change.

Comment: Works like a charm - I can finally install the update Apple has recommended now. Thanks @Travis

Comment: Deleting the derived data folder did it for me.  I had re-aquired development keys from another computer, and did everything else (delete old certs, clean build, etc.), but deleting the derived data folder was the last piece that solved it.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I've tried cleaning project, deleting derived data, unplugging device etc.. But only cleaning build folder worked!

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the derived data folder as suggested by Travis solved the problem.

Window - Projects - Select Project - Delete derived data

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the Derived Data solved the problem for me (as Travis recommended).

I was having the problem after restarting an old project with the same Bundle Identifier and signing profile.  When I went into the Projects window I saw that the old project was listed in the Projects list.  I wound up deleting the old project (along with all of its derived data) and the derived data from the current app.

This was the thing that finally solved the issue after many other attempts, including reinstalling xCode entirely.  Thanks [Travis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3039973/travis)!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Delete app on device manually
2. Clean the product
3. Run again